# abstraction and performance

Tags: performance, frameworks, abstraction

I use a lot of frameworks in my programming tasks. While these frameworks make it easy to code, I find that having more and more layers of libraries / frameworks often end up hurting performance.

I am wondering if there are any quotes / stories about how too many layers of abstraction ends up hurting application performance. Or is that no longer true?

For those who think that this question is off topic: I am interested in specific incidents with **quantifiable** performance degradation (e.g., app got 10% slower after using the X framework as opposed to writing custom code) and ways to fix the problem, not subjective opinions about what they think should happen.

Comment: I don't think they necessary *hurt* performance, but they can *hide* performance problems because you don't always know what the function is actually *doing*..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I totally agree. Would you happen to know of famous stories / anecdotes regarding that?

Comment: Not really sure that asking for anecdotes, stories, quotes on SO is on-topic

Comment: Funny, I just watched a video of Rasmus Lerdorf (creater of PHP) answer a question about PHP Frameworks with "General Frameworks Suck" with similar reasons (code bloat, performance, etc).  His comment comes around 31:40 into the video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anr7DQnMMs0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programmer's personal, subjective experience rather an actual problem or measurable question.

Answer (score 2):

There are several factors to be considered when deciding whether or not to use a third party framework:

- time to market (generally improves when using 3rd party appropriately)
- control of a technology (generally degrades for obvious reasons)
- performance (may both improve or degrade, has to be benchmarked before the decision is made)
- second order of magnitude effects: maintenance, build/release complexity

Some frameworks are well known and are generally worth using always (like SLF4J or Joda in Java or like Boost or TBB in C++).

All in all it is highly subjective and even depends on what level of AD expertise is available in your organization. With some developers may be worth writing things from scratch and have full control of the technology, with others it may be better off using third party.

Software with known EOL date should always have development cost as the final determinant.

Software known to be a strategic platform for the organization should have bias towards reasonably minimizing questionable third party dependencies.

On the anecdotes subject: I have recently come across a code that was parsing a simple command line with a hand rolled parser written in boost::spirit.